# resizable div with pure css

Tags: html, css

I want to implement resizable div with pure css and html (only) .
this is my example code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <section class="left">Left Side</section>
        <section class="center">Center</section>
        <section class="right">Right Side</section>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my scss :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
}

article {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: start;
    section {
        background-color: #2c2c2c;
    }
    .left {
        resize: horizontal;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .center {
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(134, 134, 134, 0.255);
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(134, 134, 134, 0.255);
        resize: horizontal;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .right {
        // How can fix this ?!
    }
}
```

How can style `right side` section to fill area between right side of `Center` section and right screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your column structure to `grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

article {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  justify-content: start;
}

article section {
  background-color: #2c2c2c;
}

article .left {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

article .center {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(134, 134, 134, 0.255);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(134, 134, 134, 0.255);
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

article .right {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section class="left">Left Side</section>
  <section class="center">Center</section>
  <section class="right">Right Side</section>
</article>
```